# overflow: hidden not working as I expect

Tags: html, css

I have a html page that displays a list of images generated by a server, but I don't want to display the bottom 2% of the image. My solution was to use overflow:hidden on the containing div for the image and then to give the image a 2% margin-top after setting it to display:inline-block. This worked great for a simple proof of concept page I built, but not so much for the actual page. I've uploaded both pages [here](http://singularity-id.com/overflowIssues.zip).

Edit:
jsbin pages:

[working](http://jsbin.com/otaduk)

[non-working](http://jsbin.com/eqiwax)

I've tried both chrome and IE9, but no luck in either browser

This is the html for the page that it's not working for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Test_files/ci.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="StockListTable" class="ListTable">
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 1" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 2" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(1)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 3" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(2)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 4" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(3)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 5" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(4)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 6" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(5)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 7" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(6)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 8" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(7)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 9" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(8)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 10" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(9)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 11" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(10)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 12" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(11)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 13" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(12)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 14" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(13)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 15" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(14)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 16" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(15)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 17" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(16)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 18" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(17)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 19" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(18)"/></div>
        <div class="PreviewCell"> <img style="border-style:none" alt="Preset 20" src="./Test_files/GetPreviewImage(19)"/></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
html
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.PreviewCell
{   
    width:12%;
    height:20%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    padding-left:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
}

.ListTable
{ 
    margin:0;
    width:104%;
    height:86%;
}

.PreviewCell img
{ 
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:2%;
}
```

It does add the margin to the top of the image, but it doesn't hide the overflow, it just makes the rows of images have more space between them.

Here's the page that it does work for.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .testimage
        {
            display:inline-block;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            margin-top:2%;
        }
        .container
        {
            width:12%;
            height:20%;
            overflow:hidden;
            float:left;
            padding-left:1px;
            padding-right:1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <div class="container">
        <img class="testimage" src="http://192.168.0.76/ImprovCollection/GetPreviewImage?URL=sspci://StockPresets/1&Width=75&Height=76&Color=%23000000" onclick="alert('test');"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="testimage" src="http://192.168.0.76/ImprovCollection/GetPreviewImage?URL=sspci://StockPresets/1&Width=75&Height=76&Color=%23000000" onclick="alert('test');"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="testimage" src="http://192.168.0.76/ImprovCollection/GetPreviewImage?URL=sspci://StockPresets/1&Width=75&Height=76&Color=%23000000" onclick="alert('test');"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="testimage" src="http://192.168.0.76/ImprovCollection/GetPreviewImage?URL=sspci://StockPresets/1&Width=75&Height=76&Color=%23000000" onclick="alert('test');"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm so confused as to why this isn't working that I even validated the page (which I never do) and it checked out.

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Rather than provide a `.zip` of the project, it would be better to build a quick demo online at jsbin.com.

Comment: we'r confused on what's happenning ??.. use jsfiffle(http://jsfiddle.net) to discribe your problem more efficiently..

Comment: @Jonathan I've added links for jsbin demos. That's a really nice tool, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the bottom margin removed, you can use a [negative margin cropping technique.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)

```
.PreviewCell img
{  
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-bottom: -4%;
}
```

If you're looking to remove the white line, the minimum percentage varies with browser width.

Comment: That's what I wound up going with, although I'm not entirely sure why it didn't work using a positive top margin.